# Complains about missing list_display when using TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-models

Complains about missing `list_display` when using `TabularInline`. I want to add sorting for my sub-model. I use the `SortableAdminMixin` class and `admin.TabularInline`, but `admin.TabularInline` doesn't have the right field for `SortableAdminMixin`. When I try to write `list_display = "__all__"` nothing happens
Complains about missing `list_display` when using `TabularInline`

```
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin

class ProjectStepInline(SortableAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProjectStep
    min_num = 1
    extra = 0

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProjectStepInline]
```

console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner

self.run()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run


self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper


fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run

self.check(display_num_errors=True)


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check


all_issues = checks.run_checks(


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks


new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 54, in check_admin_app

errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 85, in check


errors.extend(modeladmin.check())


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 120, in check


return self.checks_class().check(self, **kwargs)


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 639, in check


*self._check_inlines(admin_obj),


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 677, in _check_inlines


return list(chain.from_iterable(


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 678, in <genexpr>


self._check_inlines_item(obj, item, "inlines[%d]" % index)


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 716, in _check_inlines_item


return inline(obj.model, obj.admin_site).check()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adminsortable2/admin.py", line 106, in __init__


if isinstance(self.list_display_links, (list, tuple)) and len(self.list_display_links) == 0:


AttributeError: 'ProjectStepInline' object has no attribute 'list_display_links'
```

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace please?

Comment: Hi! I posted the full error. If anything I use django-admin-sortable2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `list_display_links` to your admin, with a field from your model;

```
class ProjectStepInline(SortableAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProjectStep
    min_num = 1
    extra = 0
    list_display_links = ['my_field']
```

It's not detailed in the `adminsortable2` docs, but it is included in an example;

```
@admin.register(models.SortableBook)
class SortableBookAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 12
    list_display = ['author', 'title', 'my_order']
    list_display_links = ['title']
    inlines = [ChapterInline, NotesInline]
```